# How do I stop IIS from starting up when I turn Windows on?

Tags: windows, iis

I do not want IIS to start automatically with Windows. How do I change this? Is there a setting in IIS manager? I have looked around in the menus for one but I couldn't find an option.

Comment: I would suggest that professional admins often support developers -- we all know DevOps is on the ascent at the moment.  Dev's often need certain services on or off that may differ from a production deploy.

Comment: Yes, but development environments are still explicitly [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). If you want to open the discussion about that policy I would recommend asking on [Meta](http://meta.serverfault.com/).

Comment: Regardless, this is in fact a very helpful question. Should be moved to another site? Superuser perhaps.

Comment: @HBruijn: how can this question be off-topic if it is about IIS server and the first bullet-point of the linked "on-topic" site is _"managing the hardware or software of servers"_?

Comment: @Sk8erPeter primarily because Windows 7 is not a **server** operating system. - Moving the question is only possible within 30 days of posting and although the answer is useful the question remains not topical, hence the status of closed.

Comment: @HBruijn: yes, it's true, but IIS _is_ a **server**, so I don't really understand why server-related questions would be off-topic here. :) It doesn't really matter if you install IIS on Windows Server 20xx or Windows 7-8-10. Based on your argument, Apache-related questions would also be off-topic if it was installed on Windows 7...

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In `services.msc` set World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3svc) to manual instead of automatic start.

Comment: I was writing that LOL  - just with a very small bit more detail.

Comment: If you feel like you can improve on my answer, edit away!

Comment: not at all, or I would have :)  I did upvote though!

Comment: OK I found "World Wide Web Publishing Service" but not W3svc. Is that the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it's the same

Comment: nice and simple! thanks, it's annoying when I'm a php developer and I've got windows running on these new machines with IIS installed and it starts up automatically, and installing a linux OS is impossible because of windows 8

Comment: @pythonian29033 `and installing a linux OS is impossible because of windows 8` what exactly does having Windows 8 have to do with installing Linux?

Comment: Windows 8 has this setting in the BIOS that the new ultrabooks come out with, so that windows8 can be in a sleep state when the user switches the machine off. this setting makes the BIOS ignore other boot devices/OSs when starting up and merely brings windows8 out of its sleep state so that it seems that it's starting up quicker

Comment: @pythonian29033 link, please. The common complaint is about SafeBoot, which is easily disabled and will allow Linux to be installed. I've never heard of what you're talking about.

Comment: SafeBoot is only one of the changes, that is what I was talking about, I couldn't remember the name, but when you install Linux successfully, If you restart the machine windows is corrupt, so you lose all your windows data and linux is unusable also

Comment: I don't know why Microsoft did not use IIS as its services name!